# Launching a JavaFx app from within an eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, javafx

I'm trying to launch a JavaFX app from within a eclipse plugin. Right now I have a viewpart in my plugin. When something is clicked, I do this:

```
Stage stage = new Stage();
StackPane root = new StackPane();
Scene s = new Scene(root, 300, 300);
root.getChildren().add(new javafx.scene.control.Label("Hey"));                     
stage.setScene(s);
stage.show();
```

I created a javafx eclipse plugin by creating a "Plugin from existing Jar archives" and selecting jfxrt.jar. I made my plugin depend on the javafx one, then deployed both plugins. Nothing happens when I click the button. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) an JavaFX application has to be launched with a subclass Application
b) it is not a good idea to repackage jfxrt.jar because you are missing all the native stuff

Use e(fx)clipse support to integrate JavaFX into Eclipse apps